# How to find encapsulating function name from line number

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am looking at a log file which just tells me the filename and the line number inside that file that has the Error. What I am interested is knowing the encapsulating function. For example, here are the contents of the log file

```
    Error: foo.file on line wxy
    Error: foo.file on line xyz
    .
    .
    .
```

and here are the contents of the file foo.file

```
function abc_1234 (...)
    .
    .
    .


    endfunction

    function def_442 ()
    .
    .
    .
   //Following line number is  WXY
    assign Z ==== X;

    endfunction


    function ghi(...)
    .
    .
    .


  //Following line number is  XYZ
    assign X = X;
    endfunction

   .
   .
   .
```

Based on the above log file, I want to get function names  `def` and `ghi` returned. I have tried the partial solution provided by @larsks and added `[[::blank::]]`

```
# look for function definitions and record the function name
# in the func_name variable
/function [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]*([^)]*)/ {
  func_name = substr($2, 1, index($2, "(")-1);
}

# when we reach the target line number, print out the current
# value of func_name
NR == target {
  print func_name
}
```

It is failing on `abc_1234 (...)` and `def_442 (...)` as there is a space before `(`. I can't get the above to work

Comment: @JamesBrown I am not sure if I understood your question but the idea is to get the encapsulating function name in which the Erroneous line exists

Comment: Create a [mcve] with truly representative concise, testable sample input and expected output plus show what you've tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @EdMorton I don't have a concise idea to get started on this but I am googling to see what can be done. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @tulamba, good, add your efforts which you are putting in order to solve your own problem in your post too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added something but not a whole lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to map a line number to a function definition, you'll will need to iterate through your source file looking for function definitions, and then print out the current one when you encounter a target line number.  For example, something like this:

```
# look for function definitions and record the function name
# in the func_name variable. This looks for lines matching the pattern
# function <space> <identifier>(<anything>), and records the
# <identifier> part in func_name.
/function [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]* *([^)]*)/ {
        func_name = $0
        func_name = gensub("function *", "", 1, func_name)
        func_name = gensub(" *\\(.*", "", 1, func_name)
}


# when we reach the target line number, print out the current
# value of func_name.  In awk, the variable NR represents the
# current line number, and target is a variable we expect to be
# passed in on the command line.
NR == target {
  print func_name
}
```

If you put this in a file called `findline.awk` and call it like this:

```
awk -f findline.awk -vtarget=26 mysourcefile.src
```

Then it will print the name of the function that contains line 26.  This script as written isn't terribly robust, but it hopefully gives you some ideas on how to proceed.

See the [awk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) for details about the `gensub` function.

Comment: could you explain the syntax in a step by step way for me and other beginners

Comment: added more text

Comment: I tried to do this with the comments.  What parts are unclear?

Comment: I have updated the example to work with lines that contain whitespace between the function name and parameter list.

Comment: I updated the post to explain where I am experiencing issues

Comment: may i propose the regex `/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])function[[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*[[:blank:]]*[(][^)]*)/` to include the  `_` in function name, exclude Somethingfunction kind of noisy word and treat some space

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl solution like below

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /function\s+(\w+).+?endfunction/sg) { print "$1\n" } ' tulamba.log
abc_1234
def_442
ghi

$
```